How to add multiple columns in of a CSV file and then add a column in the last column and put the summation in this column?
How to add three columns in below given sample CSV and add those to integers to the fifth column by adding them all.
Sample:-
Emdid,name,basic_sal,Allowance,Perk
11,Dave,1100,500,50
22,Gina,1000,600,50
33,Kyle,2000,300,100

Output:-
Emdid,name,basic_sal,Allowance,Perk,salary
11,Dave,1100,500,50,1650
22,Gina,1000,600,50,1650
33,Kyle,2000,300,100,2400

We can solve it using awk command but not getting how to add a new column.

import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv(“path_to_filename/filename.csv”)
df[‘salary’] = df[‘basic_sal’] + df[‘Allowance’] + df[‘Perk’]

